# PHP if/else issue using true/false

Tags: php, if-statement

My code looks like this:

```
$muted = 'true'; //Note this is only for testing
if ($muted == 'false' || $muted == '' || $do_not_text == '' || $do_not_text =='false'){
//do this first thing
}
else{
//do something else
}
```

I can't get my `else` to run. What syntax am I messing up?

Related to this, I'm storing a value in my database (that will be what's called to set `$muted` in my real code) that's either 'true', 'false', or ''. What data type should I be storing these as? Currently, I'm using `VARCHAR`, but I suspect this is all part of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$do_not_text == ''` evaluates to true. Why? Because `$do_not_text` is not defined which is a falsy value. You are comparing it to an empty string which also equates to a falsy value. So that comparison is true causing the first if statement to be evaluated as true.

Comment: Makes sense. What should I store in my database instead of an empty string to ensure this doesn't happen?

Comment: *"which also equates to a ."* - unfinished sentence there John? lol - edit: ah, I see you fixed it ;-)

Comment: Yep. Paste failed me! Fixed.

Comment: @jonmrich You need to make sure `$do_not_text` is defined and has a value you expect.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you're using strings for what should be boolean values.

```
$muted = true; // no need for quotes
```

You might also consider using the `===` operator when comparing boolean values.

```
if ($muted === false || // etc...
```

> What data type should I be storing these as?

Boolean values in MySQL are typically stored as 1 or 0.

```
field_name TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Store them as `TINYINT` with length of `1` because its only 1 and 0,  and `0` as the default value.

Then you can make `$muted = boolval($db_muted_val);` if you want, or use `$db_muted_val` as is, because `1` is `true` and `0` is `false`.

```
if ($db_muted_val) {
    // do this first thing
} else {
    // do something else
}
```